# deletion in array .. wrong with code

Tags: java

when i code this no error appears to me but when compile it >> give me error >> what is the wrong with that ??

```
public static void main (String args []){
    int arr[] = {20 , 30 ,40 , 50 , 60 ,200 };

    int searchKey = 20 ; 


    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ){

        if (arr[i]== searchKey){
            System.out.println(searchKey + "found");
            for(int z = i ; z < arr.length ;z++){
                arr[z] = arr[z+1];
            }
            for(int k=0 ; k<arr.length ; k++)
                System.out.print(arr[k] + " ");

            break;
        }
        else if (i ==  (arr.length-1) ) {
             System.out.print(searchKey+  " not found");
             break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: There is no compiler error just an IndexOutOfBoundException at runtime.

Comment: `arr[z+1]` is out of bounds, it's a runtime exception.

Comment: it give me logic error but in this line  :  arr[z] = arr[z+1];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: okey what is the solution of it  !!

Comment: con't you sorted out still?

Comment: You can't delete an array element, If you want to delete an element, then it's better to use ArrayList instead of the array.....

This way definitely you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this for loop you go in `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Replace

```
for(int z = i ; z < arr.length ;z++)
```

With `arr.length-1` instead `arr.length`:

```
for(int z = i ; z < arr.length-1 ;z++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you would get an out of bounds exception
with

```
for(int z = i ; z < arr.length ;z++) {
    arr[z] = arr[z+1];
}
```

try reducing the looping by

```
for(int z = i ; z < arr.length -1 ;z++)
```